# need to make calendar

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

we have a problem with our loop cause when we use an if statement it only shows one of our titles and not all of them

this is our code:

```
$sqldayshours = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *  FROM event;") or die("Kon de comments niet ophalen");
$event_time = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldayshours);

$title =  $event_time['event_title'];
    $day = $event_time['event_date_day'];
    $uur = $event_time['event_date_hour'];
    $ide = $event_time['event_id'];
    $idsql="day".$day."uur".$uur;

for($rij=8;$rij<19;$rij++)
    {
        echo " < tr > ";
                    for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
            {
                    $id = "day".$i."uur".$rij;
                    echo " < td id=\"$id\" name=\"$id\" class=\"events\">";
                    if($i==0){
              echo $rij.":00 ";
                  }else{ 
                                    if($idsql == $id ){ 
                                   echo $title; 
                               }
                }
        echo "< /td >";
                }`

        echo "< /tr >";

    }
```

Comment: i want to show all of the events in the calender and with the if i only get one . i tried to use loops but never get it right does one of you have an answer ?

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc only gets one row of your result, so that's probably the reason why.  Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: i checked the manual but can't really find a good replassement or change. do you know what could be used to get all the events and not only one?

Comment: anybody know how to fix it that i can get all my $title in my calender en not only the first one

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what your looking for but you can loop through all the results using something like this:

```
<?php

   while($event_time = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldayshours) ) {

       echo $event_time['title']; // or whatever you need to do.

   }

   //or alternatively

   while($event_time = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldayshours) ) {

       $results[] = $event_time;

   }

    print_r($results);
```

That allows you to loop through the results and do what you want with them.

The second pushes the results to an array where you can then use the values outside of the while loop or whatever you would like to do.

Comment: yeah i got that far too but the problem is getting the $title in every corresponding cell of the table where the id's are equal to each other when i do that with if it only shows me one where it is supossed to be but doesn't do it for  the next one's

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $sqldayshours = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *  FROM event;") or die("Kon de comments niet ophalen");
   while($event_time = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldayshours) ) {
        for($rij=8;$rij<19;$rij++)
    {
        echo " < tr > ";
                    for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
            {
                    $id = "day".$i."uur".$rij;
                    echo " < td id=\"$id\" name=\"$id\" class=\"events\">";
                    if($i==0){
              echo $rij.":00 ";
                  }else{ 
                                    if($idsql == $id ){ 
                                   echo $event_time['title']; 
                               }
                }
        echo "< /td >";
                }`

        echo "< /tr >";

    }
   }

?>
```

Comment: now it loops everything the table as well maybe the problem is the if

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sqldayshours = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *  FROM event;") or die("Kon de comments niet ophalen");

//loop all 18hours of one day
for($hour=8;$hour<19;$hour++)
{
    echo "<tr>";

    //loop all 7days
    for($day=0;$day<8;$day++)
    {
        //save the current time in the loop
        $current_time = "day".$day."uur".$hour;

        //loop all the events in the query and check for a valid one
        while($one_event = $sqldayshours->fetch_array())
        {
            $title = $one_event['event_title'];
            $day2= $one_event['event_date_day'];
            $hour2= $one_event['event_date_hour'];
            $id2 = $one_event['event_id'];
            $idsql = "day".$day2."uur".$hour2;

            echo "<td id='$current_time' name='$current_time' class='events'>";

            if($day == 0)
            {
                echo $hour.":00";
                echo "< /td >";
            }
            else if($current_time == $idsql)
            {
                echo $title;
                echo "< /td >";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "< /td >";
            }
        }

    echo "<tr>";

    }
}

?>
```

I've turned the loops around. This may take a higher load on the server, but for each row you generate, he checks if their is a valid entry in the database, if not, he continues.
Hope I'm making sense. I haven't tested this, just writen what I thought. But you may find inspiration or something in it.

I've also tried to follow your logic...

Madjdc.

Comment: after alot of tweeking it still doesnt get me all my records in there